# How to import 3D object to adobe without element 3D

Tags: video, after-effects

I've been trying to import 3D object into adobe after effects. I have element 3D installed but it requests a licence file. And it tells me that my licence file is 'invalid'. Is there any other plug-ins I can use to import 3D objects into after effects?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, After Effects comes bundled with Cinema 4D lite.
https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/c4d.html